# How to pass model object to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my razor view (cshtml), I want to pass my model object to a javascript function as a whole and have the javascript function perform some operations on it, but I'm having an issue trying to pass the model.  Here is what I have:

```
@model TestModel

<body>
...
...
<a onclick="DoSomething(@Model)">TestClickLink</a>
...
...
</body>

<script>

    function DoSomething(theModel) {
        theModel.variable1 = something
    }

</script>
```

How can I pass my current model with all it's values to the javascript function? I'm not very versed in javascript so please be detailed with your explanations if you can, any help would be appreciate it

Comment: `var model= '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'` will serialize your model to a javascript object.

Comment: If you're inside a form you can use `var model = $('#formId').serialize()`

Comment: So does this mean there's no way to pass it through the onclick function call?

Comment: What do you mean _pass it through the onclick_ What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the model through the onclick function call inside the <a> element.  This is for simplicity sake, the thing I'm trying to pass through is a complex object variable on the model, but I figured if I can get the entire model through, I should have no problem getting the variable through either.

Comment: `<a href="#" id="test">TestClickLink</a>` and `$('#test").click(function() { var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'; // do something with the model });` But you current script indicates your then setting the value of a property in the object so its unclear what the purpose of that is.

Answer (score 0):

I would try serializing your model in Json. Please make sure your model is a POCO, and without circular references. If it is so, add Json.Net to your project, if you don't have it already, and generate a script tag:

```
<head ...>
    <script>
      var theModel = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I tried the JSON encoding directly with the functioncall, and got a whole bunch of 'expected )' errors when the page is loading. Like this:

<a onclick="DoSomething(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TestModel)))">TestClickLink</a>